# Set up WordPress blog on site that already has one

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress blog on a site, say `example.com/wp-site`. I want to add a separate, unrelated blog at `example.com/travelblog/wp-site`.

I've `ftp`ed in and `mkdir`ed `/travelblog` and then tried to use [the iPad application](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wordpress/id335703880?mt=8) to add a blog there. However, I got a response something like

> Sorry, can't log you in (200-209)
>
> Received 403

I also tried adding one at `/travelblog/wp-site`. Same error.

I can't reach the person who set up the original blog.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to do one of two things:

1. Install a new instance of WordPress and configure Apache to host it at that location.
2. Create a [WordPress Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) so that you can run multiple blogs/sites off of the same WordPress installation. The big caveat here is that in order to do this on a site that already has content it's much more difficult to setup folder-based as opposed to subdomain-based.

Answer (score 2):

no sure how the iPada app works, but the standard procedure it's pretty easy

1. download wordpress, unzip and ftp the content to example.com/travelblog/wp-site
2. create a new database for this new wordpress
3. run the installation (http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to silmaril8n's suggestions #1, you should set your new Wordpress' installation to use a different table name prefix than the other Wordpress install. You can set that in the wp_config.php file at install time.